# Do I have to steal "Litany of Larceny" items during the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

So I was looking through the wiki and saw that I missed an item for the "Litany of Larceny" quest when I did Snow Veil Sanctum.  I went back and got the model ship, but when I went to Devin I did not get the conversation prompt to sell him the item.  It is the last item I need to complete the quest, and it does not show under my completed quest section.  Did I miss out on the quest because I didn't get the ship during my first trip through the dungeon?  Is this a known bug?  Or am I just missing something?  Also, I am playing on ps3, so console commands are not an option to complete the quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final item, and sometimes the Left Eye of the Falmer (final or not) can/will cause the larceny quests to bug. It is possible that the death of Mercer Frey is the cause of the glitch and there are workarounds for the  PC   and  360  .

It appears that finishing the Thieves Guild quest Darkness Returns will sometimes prevent handing in more larceny items to Delvin. [Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Larceny_Targets)

I don't think there is a fix for it on the ps3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and will be fixed by the upcoming [v1.9 patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.9):

> Fixed rare issue with being unable to turn in stolen items in “The Litany of Larceny”